# Slow wp_term_relationships query

Tags: database, mysql, terms, core

I'm running a large WP instance (currently has 28,000+ posts in custom types) and have been experiencing some odd slowdowns.  Upon analyzing the MySQL slow query log, one of the problem queries is:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_posts 
WHERE 
    wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_type IN ('s5_video', 's5_post', 's5_one_liner', 's5_image') 
    AND term_taxonomy_id = 1498
```

(s5_video, s5_post, s5_one_liner, and s5_image are our custom types)

Doing an explain on the query yields the following:

[image]

Now, 23,000 rows analyzed is a lot, but not terrible, especially for a query that isn't run too frequently.  In fact, in my manual testing, much of the time, the query only takes 50ms or so to execute (presumably because it is still in MySQL's query cache).  However, sometimes, the query takes 12-16 *seconds* to execute.

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Our mid-range VPS has plenty of power to handle this type of query (8 CPUs, 4GB RAM).  The SQL EXPLAIN result shows that MySQL is, in fact, using the keys to generate the result.  Given the capacity of our server, as well as the use of the keys, doesn't 12-16 seconds to analyze 24k rows seem a little extreme?  (That's about 1500 rows *per second*.  Yuck!)  Why is this happening?  Has this happened on anyone else's large WP instances?
2. Any suggestions on what to do?  Normally, in a situation like this, I'd add indices to speed things up, but MySQL is already using the correct keys.  And as far as I can tell, this query is built in to the Wordpress core (not part of our custom code), and is straightforward enough that I can't think of how to optimize it further... ?

Comment: 12-16 seconds seems very long. Could you limit it to one custom post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare yourself for an unsatisfying answer...

**After several days of testing, the conclusion that I've come to is that, put simply, this isn't Wordpress' "fault".**  I believe another related issue on the server was putting undue strain on the system.  This was simply one of the slower queries, which, since the server was under strain, quickly rose to the top of our slow queries log, with times between 12-16 seconds.

That doesn't mean that I'm satisfied with the join size of `23,608 (VERY BAD, VERY SLOW)`.  However, it does mean that **for others visiting this question, the resolution to your specific problem may be to examine your system as a whole to determine why this (or another) query is performing so poorly.**

Happy coding!